# Django Test Login

Tags: django, django-tests

I created a test for create user and login. In my settings I have defined the password with min_length = 8. But the test passes with a password of 3 chars. Here my settings:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator', },
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator', 'OPTIONS': {'min_length': 8}},
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator', },
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator', },]
```

My test looks like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class UsersManagersTests(TestCase):

def test_create_user(self):
    custom_user = get_user_model()
    user = custom_user.objects.create_user(email='normal@user.com', password='foo')
    self.assertEqual(user.email, 'normal@user.com')
    self.assertTrue(user.is_active)
    self.assertFalse(user.is_staff)
    self.assertFalse(user.is_superuser)
    try:
        # username is None for the AbstractUser option
        # username does not exist for the AbstractBaseUser option
        self.assertEqual(user.username, '')
        # password will be encrypted with bcrypt
        self.assertNotEqual(user.password, 'foo')
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
        custom_user.objects.create_user()
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
        custom_user.objects.create_user(username='')
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
        custom_user.objects.create_user(username='', password="foo")

def test_create_superuser(self):
    custom_user = get_user_model()
    admin_user = custom_user.objects.create_superuser(email='super@user.com', password='bla')
    self.assertEqual(admin_user.email, 'super@user.com')
    self.assertTrue(admin_user.is_active)
    self.assertTrue(admin_user.is_staff)
    self.assertTrue(admin_user.is_superuser)
    try:
        # username is None for the AbstractUser option
        # username does not exist for the AbstractBaseUser option
        self.assertEqual(admin_user.username, '')
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
        custom_user.objects.create_superuser(
            email='super@user.com', password='bla', is_superuser=False)

def test_login_user(self):
    # Create an instance of a POST request.
    self.client.login(email="normal@user.com", password="foo")
    data = {'username': 'test name'}
    res = self.client.post('/accounts/login/', data)
    self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
```

What am I missing ? Or aren't the settings not considered during tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected and [documented behaviour](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.password_validation):

> By default, validators are used in the forms to reset or change passwords and in the `createsuperuser` and `changepassword` management commands. Validators aren’t applied at the model level, for example in `User.objects.create_user()` and `create_superuser()`, because we assume that developers, not users, interact with Django at that level and also because model validation doesn’t automatically run as part of creating models.